# adding shapelib to Qt's project

Tags: qt, shapefile

can you help me, i'm working under ubuntu OS and installed shapelib through synaptic manager?
How to add this library in QtCreator?

Answer (score 0):

```
LIBS += -lshapelib
```

in your .pro file

Answer (score 0):

If shapelib is installed in your system then add

```
LIBS += -lshp
```

in .pro file of project